# Remove directory name from URL using htaccess but keep parent page

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Remove directory name from URL using htaccess, but keep the parent page.

```
https://www.example.com/faqs/page1/
https://www.example.com/faqs/page2/
https://www.example.com/faqs/page3/
https://www.example.com/faqs/page4/
https://www.example.com/faqs/page5/
https://www.example.com/faqs/page6/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/page1/
https://www.example.com/page2/
https://www.example.com/page3/
https://www.example.com/page4/
https://www.example.com/page5/
https://www.example.com/page6/
```

But

```
https://www.example.com/faqs/
```

remains the same.

I tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/faqs/(.*)$  https://www.example.com/$1
```

But it will make

```
https://www.example.com/faqs/
```

redirect to homepage too.

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: `.+` instead of `.*`...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RedirectMatch 301 ^/faqs/(.*)$  https://www.example.com/$1
> ```

To exclude the `/faq/` URL you just need to change the `*` (0 or more) quantifier to `+` (1 or more) in your capturing subpattern, so only `/faqs/<something>` matches and not `/faqs/<anything>`. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/faqs/(.+)$  https://www.example.com/$1
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Is this working? Because I am getting This page isn’t working

Comment: @user9437856 Yes, this "works". However, order of directives in `.htaccess` is important - you may have a conflict with other directives? What do you mean by "This page isn't working" exactly? Are you getting a _redirect-loop_? This directive by itself cannot cause a redirect loop.

Comment: I have only one custom post on my website and I tried your code and  I am getting This page isn't working after loading

Comment: @user9437856 If you have another question then please ask another question (you can ping me in comments). Make sure you include the URL(s) being requested and the precise response you are getting. And include your complete `.htaccess` file with this directive in place. There's nothing actually wrong with the directive in my answer. There may be something else in your config that is causing an issue. "custom post" - that sounds like you are using a CMS of some kind? If so, then you probably have mod_rewrite directives. `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive - so could result in a conflict.

Comment: I think you are right, I have to ask a new question. But let me try your above suggestion. Thank you for the help.